Using external stop control in std::jthread to avoid duplication

Unlike std::thread, the jthread logically holds an internal private member of type std::stop_source, which maintains a shared stop-state.
(cppreference link)

I want to use an external std::stop_source to control the stop behaviour of multiple threads in a coordinated way.
Example:
void thread_function(std::stop_token stoken)
{
  while (!stoken.stop_requested())
  {
    // Do something
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::stop_source ssource;  // common stop source
  std::jthread t1(thread_function, ssource.get_token());
  std::jthread t2(thread_function, ssource.get_token());

  // ...

  ssource.request_stop();

  // ...
}

If I provide an std::stop_token to a jthread's constructor, does this prevent the jthread from creating its own internal std::stop_source, since an external stop_source already exists?

why worry about the stop_source of t1 or t2 ? Your ssource can stop both as desired, whether t1 and t2 have another stop_source that is not used doesnt matter, does it?

It is probably implementation dependant. But since all main standard library implementations have proven themselves to be efficient in general, I would guess you don't have to worry about it in this case as well.

The jthread constructor merely forwards additional arguments to the function to be called. It does not do anything else with those parameters. In your code there are 3 stop sources, the ones of t1 and t2 are just not used to stop them.
From cppreference:

The new thread of execution starts executing:
std::invoke(decay-copy(std::forward<F>(f)), get_stop_token(),
            decay-copy(std::forward<Args>(args))...)  (until C++23)

std::invoke(auto(std::forward<F>(f)), get_stop_token(),
        auto(std::forward<Args>(args))...)    (since C++23)

if the expression above is well-formed, otherwise starts executing:
std::invoke(decay-copy(std::forward<F>(f)),
            decay-copy(std::forward<Args>(args))...).     (until C++23)

std::invoke(auto(std::forward<F>(f)),
           auto(std::forward<Args>(args))...).    (since C++23)


In different words: Either the callable you pass as first constructor argument has one parameter more than the number of arguments you pass and can accept a stop_token. Then the constructor will pass its own stop_token. If not, the jthread constructor will not pass its own stop_token but only forwards the arguments you passed.
In your example, the first variant is not well-formed because your function does take a single stop_token which is included in Args.... Though, the two threads t1 and t2 still have a stop_source you can get via get_stop_source (or their tokens via get_stop_token).
